# Capture multiple lines using reg ex in python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to write a regex that captures "my_code" line and the two lines that are indented unde it only

```
//abs[matches(@class,"her")] 
  //abs[matches(@class,"him")]
```

i was using `my_code\n\s\s(.+)`

```
my_code
  //abs[matches(@class,"her")] 
  //abs[matches(@class,"him")]
xxxx   //time
xxxxx   //h1
```

i was using `my_code\n\s\s(.+)`

```
my_code
  //abs[matches(@class,"her")] 
  //abs[matches(@class,"him")]
xxxx   //time
xxxxx   //h1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\s` matches a space and also a newline.

To make sure it is indentend, you might match 2 times the newline and 1 or more spaces or tabs `[\t ]+` using a character class.

```
^my_code\r?\n[\t ]+.+\r?\n[ \t]+.+
```

- `^` Start of string
- `my_code\r?\n` match literally followed by a newline
- `[\t ]+` Match 1+ spaces or tabs
- `.+` Match 1+ times any char except a newline
- `\r?\n[ \t]+.+` Again match a newline, 1+ spaces or tabs and any char except a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lf5gMy/1)

To match the indented part 1 or more times, you could repeat a non capturing group and use a quantifier `+`

```
^my_code(?:\r?\n[\t ]+.+)+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V2Pwoe/1)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working like this:

```
test_str  = """ 
    my_code
      //abs[matches(@class,"her")] 
      //abs[matches(@class,"him")]
    xxxx   //time
    xxxxx   //h1
"""
pattern = re.compile('my_code\n\s+[^\n]+\n\s+[^\n]+')
res = re.search(pattern, test_str)
print(res.group())
```

The `[^\n]+` means match every character except new line and there should be 1 or more of these characters. This produces output like:

```
my_code
      //abs[matches(@class,"her")] 
      //abs[matches(@class,"him")]
```